# Replacing first character of each word without affecting the inside ones

Tags: regex, string, powershell-3.0

I am trying to replace the first character of each key word in PowerShell but unable to find the correct pattern to get the required result. Somehow I am able to manage to get the replacement, but other values are affecting which are acting as a value i.e "Gii-test-api.ne" converting into "Gii$test$api$ne".

**For example:**

My string is (replacing `-` with `$`):

```
$values = -CertThumb 1234567 -serverCertThumb 75659600 -MaintenancePeriod 60 -apiProtocol https -Port 8973 -Uri Gii-test-api.ne
```

Expected output:

```
$CertThumb 1234567 $serverCertThumb 75659600 $MaintenancePeriod 60 $apiProtocol https $Port 8973 $Uri Gii-test-api.ne
```

Tried command:

```
$values.ToString() -replace ('^*\-','$')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex replace where `-` chars are only matched if not preceded with a word char:

```
$values -replace '\B-','$'
```

Or, if you only want to replace `-` that is preceded with whitespace or at the start of the string:

```
$values -replace '(?<!\S)-','$'
```

Here, `\B` matches any location other than a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (i.e. here, `-` only matches when not preceded with a letter, digit or `_`) and the `(?<!\S)` negative [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) matches a location in the string that is either start of string or is preceded with a whitespace.

Note that the replacement can be either `'$'` or `'$$'` (a literal `$` in the replacement will be parsed here as a `$` char, but in case you replace with a `$`+digit you will have to escape `$` with another `$`).

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CB-&i=-CertThumb%201234567%20-serverCertThumb%2075659600%20-MaintenancePeriod%2060%20-apiProtocol%20https%20-Port%208973%20-Uri%20Gii-test-api.ne&r=%24).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for support !!